# Layout Behavior in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I've been playing around with web development and I've noticed that in Firefox, my elements are getting pushed to the right versus down, which is what it should be (which happens in Chrome).

[image]

I am by no means a Guru. Is there any way to prioritize wrapping versus pushing? I have tried inserting line breaks and setting both to display:block. That does not seem to be the problem.

This is the CSS for the bar:

```
.tiq-editor-bar
{
    z-index:1;
    overflow:hidden;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    border-top: solid 1px #AAA;
    text-align:center;
    display:none;
    position:relative;
    color:#AAA;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-size:14px;
}
```

This is the CSS for the gallery wrapper (the white out-lined thing)

```
#tiq-ui-gallery-wrapper
{
    min-height: 500px;
    background:url(../img/portfolio/empty.png) center no-repeat;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

And for the gallery itself:

```
.tiq-theme-gallery
{
    width:600px;
    height:400px;
    resize:vertical;
    border:solid 1px #eee;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

Thanks!

EDIT: The gallery is positioned relatively, BTW. I am using Galleria and that gives the container:

```
.galleria-container {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #000;
    display:block;
}
```

EDIT EDIT:

Here is a JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/RyBz9/2/

Comment: Not enough info. Need a jsfiddle or a link. From what I've found, 'resize' does not work in any browser with standard syntax though it's possible it works in webkit.

Comment: resize doesn't really have any effect on it

Comment: Update: Here you go, JSFiddle posted: http://jsfiddle.net/RyBz9/2/

Comment: i'm using firefox 10 and your problem doesn't seem to exist

Comment: @XepterX: weird... I am using Firefox 10, and the problem exists

Comment: ah, i saw it, didn't notice it went to the right side due to me using a smaller resolution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
.tiq-editor-bar
{
    float:left;
}
```

to

```
.tiq-editor-bar
{
    float:none;
}
```

Comment: I am happy I could help. :-)  Maybe you can just remove this `float` line instead of changing it.

Comment: Yes, this was a remnant of an old layout that I forgot to remove.